# Windows 10 UPGRADE modifies apache service by adding an "N" in service script

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, windows-10

I was testing windows 10 upgrade and have the following problem. (See screenshot below)

1. Install Program in windows 8.1 to C:\Program Files\PHP Point of Sale Stack
2. Upgrade to windows 10
3. The windows service gets setup where there is an error in event viewer

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Could not open configuration file C:/Program Files/PHP Point of Sale Stack/apache2/conf/httpd.conf**N**: The system cannot find the file specified.

NOTICE HOW THE “N” is added to the end. This was added AFTER upgrading to windows 10. Is this a issue with windows 10? Why would it modify my service?

[image: Event Viewer]

Comment: I believe there is something wrong with the windows 10 upgrade process. Where can I submit a bug report?

Comment: Same here. Any solutions around?

Comment: I wish I had an answer....I don't want to pay money to submit a bug to MS.

Comment: Could you open services.msc and check the command line for the Apache Service?